# Reduce Time To Create Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a temp table using the script below and it's taking forever. I was hoping someone might have some tips on how I could rewrite the code to speed things up.

```
Select ProductName,
        Convert(date, messagereceived) as ProcessDate,
        datepart(hour,messagereceived) as ProcessHour, 
        Pipename,Partnername,
        DaTEDIFF(SECOND,MessageCreated,MessageReceived) as TransitTime,
        DaTEDIFF(SECOND,MessageReceived,ProcessingStarted) as WaitTime,
        DaTEDIFF(SECOND,ProcessingStarted,ProcessingFinished) as ProcessingTime
into #Temp
from Table ml 
inner join MessagingProduct mp on ml.MessagingProductId=mp.ProductId
where ml.processingstarted > '2015-09-08' and ml.processingstarted < '2015-09-09'
AND 
ml.MessagingSystemId=1
```

Comment: How long is "forever"? What do your source tables looks like? What indexes do they currently have? How much data do they contain?

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
Select  . . .
into #Temp
from Table ml inner join
     MessagingProduct mp
     on ml.MessagingProductId = mp.ProductId
where ml.processingstarted > '2015-09-08' and
      ml.processingstarted < '2015-09-09' AND 
      ml.MessagingSystemId = 1 ;
```

You want indexes on the table.  The most important index is a composite index on `Table(MessagingSystemId, processingStarted, MessagingProductId)`.  In addition, an index on `MessagingProduct(ProductId, ProductName)` would also be helpful.